# Where can I check if the PARAMETER_SENSITIVE_PLAN_OPTIMIZATION is enabled or not on a db?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2022

Where can I check if the PARAMETER_SENSITIVE_PLAN_OPTIMIZATION is enabled or not on a db?

I tried looking for it in sys.databases and also under the database properties UI.

Is query store enabling a prerequisite for this feature?

Answer (score 2):

To see how it is currently configured you can check:

```
    USE [DATABASENAME]
    SELECT * 
    FROM sys.database_scoped_configurations
    WHERE [name]='PARAMETER_SENSITIVE_PLAN_OPTIMIZATION'
```

To turn it on use:

```
    USE [DATABASENAME]
    ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET PARAMETER_SENSITIVE_PLAN_OPTIMIZATION = ON
```

And to turn it off use:

```
    USE [DATABASENAME]
    ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET PARAMETER_SENSITIVE_PLAN_OPTIMIZATION = OFF
```

Answer (score -2):

`PARAMETER_SENSITIVE_PLAN_OPTIMIZATION` is enabled by default in SQL Server 2022. However, it may be turned off at the query or database level. To disable it at the database level:

`ALTER DATABASE [database_name] SET PARAMETER_SENSITIVE_PLAN_OPTIMIZATION = OFF;`

To turn it back on, use:

`ALTER DATABASE [database_name] SET PARAMETER_SENSITIVE_PLAN_OPTIMIZATION = ON;`

Comment: I have migrated few databases, so for them I want to check if it is enabled or not. Is there a simple query to check this?